# Colour Picker package of Sublime Text 3 not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python3, sublime-text, pygtk

I have installed the sublime text Color Picker package, but pressing Ctrl+Shift+C does not pop up color picker gui.

I ran the the linux_colorpicker.py file, and I did get the color picker gui, but for some reason it does not show up in sublime text.
Here's the result of running the python file.
[Color Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfYpY.png)

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should install package python-gtk2 in your system. It is not in default repositories, therefore:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/python2-stuff
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2
```

Besides, to allow the tool output color codes to your files, you will need to update `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/ColorPicker/lib/linux_colorpicker.py` changing the line:

```
if color_sel.run() == getattr(Gtk, 'RESPONSE_OK', Gtk.ResponseType.OK):
```

to:

```
if color_sel.run() == getattr(Gtk, 'RESPONSE_OK', Gtk.ResponseType):
```

Answer (score 0):

I sloved the problem by changing package :

use can used https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorHelper instead ;)